# what is wrong with postcondition in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

```
function sumTo( a:array<int>, k:int, j:int)  : int
  requires a != null;
  requires 0 <= k && k <=a.Length;
  requires k <= j && j <= a.Length-1;
  decreases j;
  reads a;
{
  if (k == j) then a[k] else sumTo(a, k, j-1) + a[j]
}

method prod(t:array<int>)  modifies t
requires t!=null  && t.Length>=2
ensures forall k: int :: 0 <= k < t.Length ==> t[k]== sumTo(old(t), k, t.Length-1)
{
    
    var i := t.Length - 2;
    while i>=0
        invariant t.Length-1>i>=-1;
        decreases i;
    {
        t[i] := t[i]+t[i+1];
        i := i-1;
    }

}
```

returns this error :

- web.dfy(17,4): Error BP5003: A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
- web.dfy(13,8): Related location: This is the postcondition that might not hold.

Comment: To reason about while loops, dafny requires loop invariant. If you hover over while statement in your editor, it states problem lies in while statement. Try providing loop invariant to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I did manage to solve this in the end though changed `sumTo()` to make it easier (specifically operating over sequences rather than arrays).  Here's how it looks:

```dafny
function sumTo(a:seq<int>, k:int)  : int
requires 0 ≤ k ∧ k < |a|;
decreases |a| - k;
{
  if (k+1) == |a| then a[k]
  else a[k] + sumTo(a,k+1)
}

method prod(t:array<int>)
  modifies t;
  requires t.Length ≥ 2;
  ensures ∀ k: int ∙ 0 ≤ k < t.Length ⟹ t[k]== sumTo(old(t[..]), k)
{

    var i ≔ t.Length - 2;
    while i ≥ 0
      invariant -1 ≤ i < t.Length - 1;
      // Last element unchanged
      invariant t[t.Length-1] == old(t[t.Length-1]);
      // Everything upto (and including) ith element unchanged
      invariant ∀ k:int ∙ 0 ≤ k ≤ i ⟹  t[k] == old(t[k]);
      // Everything else matches the sum we want
      invariant ∀ k:int ∙ i < k ∧ k < t.Length ⟹  t[k] == sumTo(old(t[..]), k);
    {
      t[i] ≔  t[i] + t[i+1];
      i ≔  i - 1;
    }
}
```

You can we needed three loop invariants in the end, and I've commented what they are doing.